# When do the properties in a mxml declaration get committed to the object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

If I do something like:

```
<myComponent id="foo" title="bar" />
```

The parameters don't seem to be available immediately within the component. When *do* they become available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Flex Docs:.

```
Flex dispatches the creationComplete event once for a component after the component is created and initialized.
```

Once a component is created and initialized, you can use its properties.  Remember, all children components are created and initialized before their parents.

Answer (score 0):

creationComplete will dispatch when all parts are completed.